# Php WordPress, what does this function?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

A newbie question, I've been reading themes and have seen this type of string often..

```
<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
```

So I'm wondering.

1. Does it do the same as php include?
2. Does it ask for a file "bloginfo(name)"
3. Does it read the Sql?
4. What is it?

I've also seen

`<? php hdbody( ); ?>`

Comment: Have you looked it up in [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)?

Comment: the documentation isn't directly written for dummies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WordPress documentation, it echoes a information about the site `bloginfo( string $show = '' )`. It uses `get_bloginfo( $show, 'display' )` to accomplish that. In that case you are echoing the 'name', that is the site title: `‘name‘ – Displays the “Site Title” set in Settings > General. This data is retrieved from the “blogname” record in the wp_options table.` Yes, this value is in the data base, for more informatin access: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

Answer (score 0):

It will print (display) the name of your wordpress site wherever that code is being used

The name of your wordpress site can be found under *General Settings*

[image: WordPress Site Name]